# Setting USB_QUIRK_CONFIG_INTF_STRINGS at runtime

Tags: linux-kernel, usb

I bought a cheap MIDI keyboard for testing something and I found out it's not working on Linux. It keeps constantly reconnecting. After some messing with Wireshark I figured out it's responding with `EPROTO` when trying to get the string for the configuration descriptor (`iConfiguration`).

After more googling, I found out that there is already a way to stop the kernel asking for that descriptor using `USB_QUIRK_CONFIG_INTF_STRINGS`, but I can only see it as setting that is compiled into the kernel.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/core/quirks.c
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/core/message.c#L1912

Do you know if there is some way to configure this without rebuilding kernel with a custom patch?

Comment: It seems not possible. This is the patch I ended up using. https://code.oxygene.sk/lukas/worlde-easykey-linux/blob/master/worlde-easykey-usb-quirks.diff